# Get URL autocomplete to match around subdomain

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, url, autocomplete, subdomain

A variety of sites that I use have the company name behind a subdomain, e.g.

```
app.asana.com
<mycompany>.salesforce.com
mail.protonmail.com
<mycompany>.latticehq.com
```

I'd like to be able to type in `lattice` and have it autocomplete to `<mycompany>.latticehq.com`. I visit these sites often and feel like I expect the browser bar to figure out that every time I type in "lattice" I'm trying to go to that URL.

In both Chrome and Firefox, the correct URL just appears as one of the suggested results, typically ~5 entries down, but does not autocomplete in the way that typing `app` autocompletes to `app.asana.com`.

I've tried to make the mapping explicit, so I have bookmarks for all of my key sites where the bookmark name is what I'd like to type in. For example,

```
{
    "name": "lattice",
    "url": "<mycompany>.latticehq.com"
}
```

However, the bookmarks don't seem to impact the autofill behaviour.

Even more frustratingly, because I go to `<mycompany>.salesforce.com` more often than I go to `<mycompany>.com`, when I type in `<mycompany>` it autocompletes to SalesForce.

I use both Chrome and Firefox and find this issue in both. Are there any ways in either browser to adjust the autocomplete algorithm to make it match more generously around subdomains? I.e if I type `salesforce` it autocompletes to `<mycompany>.salesforce.com`?

Comment: You could have these links on your home page.  You could even put such a page on your website.  Its only links so it doesnt has to be protected by password.

Comment: I can already click the bookmarks in the bookmarks bar, but I'd rather be able to do it with the keyboard. I'm already pushing ctrl-t to open a new tab and then typing so my hands are already on the keyboard.